# How to change url pattern for index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp

How can I change the URL pattern for index.jsp. I want to change the URL `http://localhost:8084/eclinical/index.jsp` to `http://localhost:8084/eclinical/home`. Below is the web.xml file:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>    
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>about</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/about.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>    

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>about</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what your are doing on calling 'home' action? Are your redirecting to any jsp?

Comment: Your existing config seems ok. What does index.jsp contain?

Comment: No I am not redirecting to any jsp page. After running the project I wanted the link to show as /home and not index.jsp

Comment: @mushfek0001 index.jsp is the home page.

Comment: In you want to redirect to /home at startup then change welcome-file to home.

Comment: I dont have file /home as such. I just wanted to map with index.jsp.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a jsp as a servlet using the jsp-file tag in the servlet definition. You can thus provide a path mapping to your jsp in web.xml

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>myIndexJsp</servlet-name>
      <jsp-file>index.jsp</jsp-file>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>myIndexJsp</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```